# Force 'static lifetime for an Arc<Mutex<i32>>

Tags: rust

I would like to make a variant of this [program](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html#atomic-reference-counting-with-arct) where my goal is to spawn a new thread calling a callback inside another spawned thread and the `cb` is declared outside the `handle` and keeping full parallelisation :

```rust
let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

let cb = || {
    let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
    for _ in 0..9 {
        let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();
        *num += 1;
    }
};

let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    for _ in 0..9 {
        thread::spawn(cb);
    }
})
.join();

println!("Result: {}", *counter.lock().unwrap());
```

Unfortunately, I got this error :

```
`counter` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enoughrustcE0597
tests_spawn.rs(28, 5): `counter` dropped here while still borrowed
tests_spawn.rs(12, 18): value captured here
tests_spawn.rs(22, 17): argument requires that `counter` is borrowed for `'static`
```

How can change the lifetime of the `counter` variable to make it `static` ?

Comment: Keep in mind that `Arc<Mutex<i32>>` is complete overkill for a thread-safe counter, and an [`atomic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI32.html) would suffice.

Comment: @isaactfa Thank you for the information, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner option is probably to use the [scoped threads API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html), which automatically joins the child threads. Plus, you don't even need `Arc`.

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let counter = Mutex::new(0);

    let cb = || {
        for _ in 0..9 {
            let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();
            *num += 1;
        }
    };

    thread::scope(|s| {
        for _ in 0..9 {
            s.spawn(cb);
        }
    });

    println!("Result: {}", *counter.lock().unwrap());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da294ec2ea3f2c08c4d54877e0866928)

Comment: Thank you. I've just moved the callback outside the thread scope and everything works like a charm.

Comment: Actually if you use scoped threads, you don't even need the `Arc`. See edit